# Spring AMQP Converting from a Message

Tags: spring-amqp

According to [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/_reference.html#_converting_from_a_message_2)  when using @RabbitListener annotation to configure listener

> the inferred type information is added to the MessageProperties; this allows the converter to convert to the argument type of the target method

so i can use custom pojo to convert in.

My question - is it works in the same way when xml-based strategy used to configure listener: `<rabbit:listener-container>
        <rabbit:listener ref=...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; that uses a simpler `MessageListenerAdapter`.

When using that form, if there is no type information in the message headers, you have to configure the message converter to tell it what type you want the data converted to...

```
<rabbit:listener-container message-converter="jsonConverter">
    <rabbit:listener ref="listener" method="handleFoo" queue-names="input.foo" />
</rabbit:listener-container>

<bean id="listener" class="com.example.Listener" />

<bean id="jsonConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter">
    <property name="classMapper">
        <bean class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.DefaultClassMapper">
            <property name="defaultType" value="com.example.Foo" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and

```
public class Listener {

    public void handleFoo(Foo foo) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }

}
```

and

```
Foo [bar=bar]
Foo [bar=bar]
```

from

```
{ "bar" : "bar" }
```

with

```
content_type: application/json
```